# Serve Pages from PHP Handler Based on Session or GET/POST Data

Tags: php

I would like to use PHP to serve different pages based on session or GET data.

For example, if $_SESSION['user_id'] is not set I would like my index.php file for https://example.com to show a page that says "Sign up for Example.com!", but if $_SESSION['user_id'] is set I would like to serve a Home page.  I would like both the "Sign Up" and "Home" pages to appear as https://example.com.

I tried using PHP includes based on the data, but this did not work - the error message was "GET https://example.com/favicon.ico 500 (Internal Server Error)" - I think because the page is not formatted to be pulled from an 'include' statement and has PHP and html.  I would like to keep the pages usable in a standalone fashion, as well as through this handler.

Is there some PHP function or method to say "stop execution and serve the php file from this location instead"?

**Edit**

I understand how to use the 'if' statement to determine my criteria.  I don't understand how to serve a page from a different file without using an 'include' statement (which requires the page to be reformatted) or a header redirect, which will show a different URL.

Comment: `if ($some_condition) { do_something(); }`, basically. php is a toolbox with screwdrivers, hammers, and occasional swiss army knife. there's rarely a `do_exactly_what_only_one_person_in_the_universe_needs()` function. learn to use the basic tools to accomplish complex things, instead of looking for a complex tool that can only accomplish one thing.

Comment: Or better : `if ($some_magical_condition_from_stack) { do_magic(); }`

Comment: This is not really answerable without specifics of how your code is structured. You can do something like `include('otherfile.php'); exit();` but it sounds like you need to use a front controller to load the appropriate view files.

Comment: Returning a 500 error from favicon.ico is possibly unrelated to the PHP code, and more likely related to the web server's configuration. Look in its error log to find out the details of the 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

Use isset to check whether session is active or not

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
{
header("location:index.php");
}
else
{
header("location:signup.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use a conditional to determine if `$_SESSION['user_id']` is set then use the [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function to redirect the user to the page of choice.  There are probably a variety of ways to do this.